# How common is it to get a last minute desert tour in Marrakech?

Tags: tours, solo-travel, morocco, deserts, marrakech

As per the title, I'm heading to Marrakech and wanting to do a tour either 4D/3N or 5D/4N. However I am travelling by myself (first time ever) and am having trouble finding an open group to go with as doing a private 4WD tour just by myself is a bit out of my price range. All the tour companies I emailed have no groups available.

It was suggested to me by the Riad I booked to just organise this when I arrive, but I'm not sure how normal that is and whether I will be able to get a place - I'm going over the easter holidays. I also really don't want to go in a big group either - I basically need another single traveler or 3.

So, what are my chances on finding a last minute tour in Marrakech going to the desert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously it'll depend on the time of year, but my feeling in Marrakech was that something would 'appear' if you needed it, they were always keen to make some cash.

We didn't have time for the desert tours, but hoped to do a day tour to a nearby river valley. Lo and behold our Riad owner suddenly had a friend running a tour, and indeed came along himself.

This was in November, however, and seasonal variations will occur in demand. We can't possibly be certain, but you could consider hopping on forums like the Lonely Planet and seeing if anyone else is looking for a tour too. Or ask your Riad to ask other guests in advance.

Otherwise, there's still PLENTY to do in and around Marrakech.

Comment: I do mention that I am going at easter time. Shortly after writing the question, I posted to both TA and LP forums, hopefully something will come out of it. I get the same feeling that things just materialize if there is cash - I just dont want to get there, then find out that all they try to take advantage of me because I have no other choice (and missing the Sahara is not a choice in my case)

Comment: Yeah I saw the Easter bit, that's why I said it'd vary from my November visit :)  We can't predict exactly how common it'd be, but yeah, I'm still gutted myself that I didn't get to the desert, although Marrakech was awesome, so can understand your desire to get there!